# configure multiple server to support sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

I planned to migrate redis server to a new one with sidekiq running, but doesn't want to stop the current application running. And I don't want to use redis cluster which is still alpha version.
My thought is to ask sidekiq to write to new redis server, but pulls from both of them, so that once the workers in old redis are completed, the new one can totally take over all workers. I think this solution is feasible, but I have no idea how to make it happen.

This is my sidekiq.rb:

```
sidkiq_config = YAML.load(ERB.new(Rails.root.join('config/redis.yml').read).result)

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.logger.level = Logger::ERROR
  config.redis = { :url => "redis://redis2.staging:6379", :namespace => "app_#{Rails.env}:sidekiq" }
  config.redis = { :url => "redis://redis.staging:6379", :namespace => "app_#{Rails.env}:sidekiq" }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.logger.level = Logger::ERROR
  config.redis = { :url => "redis://redis2.staging:6379", :namespace => "app_#{Rails.env}:sidekiq" }
end
```

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the easiest solution is to run *two instances* of sidekiq - one that reads from the old cluster, and one that reads from the new cluster

```
sidkiq_config = YAML.load(ERB.new(Rails.root.join('config/redis.yml').read).result)

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.logger.level = Logger::ERROR
  if ENV['read_from_new']
    config.redis = { :url => "redis://redis2.staging:6379", :namespace => "app_#{Rails.env}:sidekiq" }
  else 
    config.redis = { :url => "redis://redis.staging:6379", :namespace => "app_#{Rails.env}:sidekiq" }
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.logger.level = Logger::ERROR
  config.redis = { :url => "redis://redis2.staging:6379", :namespace => "app_#{Rails.env}:sidekiq" }
end
```

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to the same problem. The configuration you suggest doesn't read from both the servers at the same time. Can you suggest how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can update to a recent version of sidekiq and use [Sharding](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Sharding).

```rb
REDIS_A = ConnectionPool.new { Redis.new(...) }
REDIS_B = ConnectionPool.new { Redis.new(...) }

# To create a new connection pool for a namespaced Sidekiq worker:
ConnectionPool.new do
  client = Redis.new(:url => "Your Redis Url")
  Redis::Namespace.new("Your Namespace", :redis => client)
end

# Create a job in the default redis instance
SomeWorker.perform_async

# Push a job to REDIS_A using the low-level Client API
client = Sidekiq::Client.new(REDIS_A)
client.push(...)
client.push_bulk(...)

Sidekiq::Client.via(REDIS_B) do
  # All jobs defined within this block will go to B
  SomeWorker.perform_async
end
```

#### To quite sidekiq, click the quite button in the UI

[image: Sidekiq UI]

Comment: I am looking for a different configuration. I have jobs already in my old Redis Server and I will be pushing the newer jobs only to new Redis Server. However, when I switch to the new Server, there might still be jobs in my old Redis Server and I want to ensure those jobs can be processed by some worker(s)

Comment: After starting the new server you can just quiet the queue on the old server. This allows it to finish what it has started and not pick up any new jobs.

Comment: I am new to Sidekiq; so can you please add some details, like the steps to follow. What should my Sidekiq.configure_server look like and what are the steps to quiet the queue on the old server?

Comment: In the sidekiq UI, there is a `quiet` button. On the busy tab.

Comment: I haven't used sharding but since it isn't anything specified in the documentation I would think the `Sidekiq.configure_server` would be identical on both servers and would not change from your current configuration

Comment: Currently, my sidekiq configuration looks like this ```Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
  # Add chewy middleware from lib/sidekiq/chewy_middleware.rb
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::ChewyMiddleware, :atomic
  end
end``` 

As you can see, the server is currently pointing to only one Redis server. I dont need any changes to the client config as the clients will push jobs onto the new Redis Server. However, the server configuration needs to include the new server. Please suggest how can the new server be included

Comment: You will have to run a separate server for each client. Notice, note 3 [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Sharding#limitations)